# Using wget and Awk to count similar expressions

Tags: unix, bash, wget, awk

I am trying to create a script that uses `wget` to download a data set and then `awk` to sort though the file and tell you the most common filter used which is `$14` column. So far I have the `wget` function working as seen below,

```
wget -O- http://energy.gov/sites/prod/files/FieldSampleAirResults_0.csv
```

But then would I pipe that to an `awk` script or should I try to do it all in one script? Also, I know how you would check for common words, it would be something like

```
$14=="charcoal" {++charcoal}
```

but I am not sure how to implement this in an `awk` script. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, kevin

Comment: Why does this belong on Server Fault? I have voted to move it to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

This prints the type of filter that occurs most.

```
wget -O- http://energy.gov/sites/prod/files/FieldSampleAirResults_0.csv | awk -F, '
    {
        filters[$14]++
    }
    END {
        for (filter in filters) {
            if (filters[filter] > max) {
                max = filters[filter]
                type = filter
            }
        }
        print type
    }'
```

You can easily print each of the types and their counts, if you prefer. AWK can do the sorting, if needed, or you can use the external `sort` utility.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `uniq` to handle the counting:

```
wget -O- http://energy.gov/sites/prod/files/FieldSampleAirResults_0.csv | cut -d, -f14 | sort | uniq -c
```

Note that this isn't going to handle quoted fields containing a comma correctly. If you need to handle that you need something which actually understands the CSV format, like Python's [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module:

```
python -c 'import csv; import sys; [sys.stdout.write(row[14]+"\n") for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin)]'
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help! another question, how would i change the field separator to commas?

Comment: use `awk -F,` instead of just awk. btw, you can also change output delimiter via OFS variable inside of awk.

Comment: cut is probably a simpler tool in this case (updated answer).